# How to know when Spring/CXF is ready to take requests?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, cxf

I have a java web application using Apache CXF and JAX/RS to implement an API. We are running our webapp under tomcat. I need to implement something in my application that calls out to an external service, which may call my application back again. I need to call that external service only after CXF finishes initializing and is ready to accept external API requests. I have checked out servlet context listeners, CXFServlet, application context refresh, and other things, but can't see anything that is called late enough in the process for CXF to begin accepting requests. Or do I need to trigger on some event from tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

If you define the CXF dependency as bean in spring configuration it will be loaded and ready when application starts. As you are aware spring beans are loaded and resolved during application startup, you can additionally have pre initialization and post initialization functions e.g. @PostConstruct.

Example configuration from reference https://www.luckyryan.com/2013/06/15/apache-cxf-exception-handler-for-jaxrs-rest/ :

```
<!-- rest container -->
<jaxrs:server id="sampleSerivceREST" address="/rest">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="sampleServiceRESTGateway"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
        <bean class="com.luckyryan.sample.service.ExceptionHandler"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>

<!-- soap container -->
<jaxws:endpoint
        id="sampleServiceSOAP"
        implementor="#sampleServiceSOAPGateway"
        address="/soap"
        serviceName="sampleSoapService"/>
```

Comment: Well, right, I have that. The problem is, the ApplicationContext instantiates all the Spring beans early on in its initialization cycle. Unfortunately, CXF is only available to accept requests much later. I'm sure there's something that can be tapped, I'm just not sure what it is.

Comment: Are you defining <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> for CXF servlet?

Comment: Well, it's <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>, but yes. I'm not sure why it takes so long to get to the point where CXF is answering requests, but it does. That's why I was hoping there was some secret callback or event I was missing.

Comment: As I understand you want to check if CXFServlet is initialized or not. You can use this http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html to check this.

Comment: Also keep the startup order to 1 so it will initialize soon if possible.